# How to zip multiple images and post to server using google recommended HTTPURLConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-image

How to zip multiple images and post to server using google recommended HTTPURLConnection? For example 50 images available getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) directory,

1. Can I use Gzip to club and compress as a single file?
2. How many images can i club in a single file?
3. What is the maximum size of compressed file post to server using HTTPURLConnection?
4. Can I use [Multipart HTTP request](http://www.androidsnippets.com/multipart-http-requests) to post the compressed file?
5. Is it any best practice available in android to post multiple images to server?

Comment: You won't get reasonable compression rates with images. GIF, JPG and PNG are already compressed. And you need a special server side logic because "normal" servers do not expect uploads to be compressed.

Comment: How do I club multiple .jpg image files into a single file and post in HttpURLConnection?

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` use keep-alive by default. Why not send each image by its own POST? In case of error you know exactly which images already arrived at the server. When "clubing" them together, you have to retry with the whole chunk every time.

Comment: I try to reduce no of POST to server by zipping image files,because it saves battery.Is it any google recommended way to post multiple images? can I use MultipartEntity with HTTPUrlConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Gzip compresses only streams and doesn't maintain a directory of files. You could use "java.util.zip.*" or JTar to tar the files and then Gzip. Depends on what you have server-side.
2. This should be restricted only by bandwidth.
3. Restrictions might exist on server-side (php.ini e.g.), not for Android
4. Multi-Part might be a way to solve your problem. But AFAIK there is no appropriate implementation for HttpURLConnection. And it's possible that your binary files "expand" the payload by beeing transformed to Base64 encoded, 7-Bit Strings (I'm not really sure about this point).
5. I don't know. But a very important point here is that you should transfer the images in a background service, especially when you build big chunks of data. Even AsyncTask might fall short, because lifetime might be dependent on the activity and when uploading a large amout of data the activity could already be destroyed. Have a look at [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). If you don't use the library, at least copy the strategy they use. Personally, I'd begin with binary uploading image by image, each with a new HttpURLConnection. Android will maintain an open connection (keep-alive), the traffic can be binary and the only thing you lose is some time (latency). But this would be a lot easier to implement on client-side and probably on server-side, too.

Comment: Post image as file or binary data?Which is best for HTTP Post?